# @Transactional save for springboot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to implement entity `save` method that

- saves entity to database
- returns attached entity
- sets entity.id to request body
- makes call to external service
- updates entity field 'externalId' with corresponding field from response
- flushes entity to DB

rolls back transaction if external services responds with error.

What I tried to do

```java
    @Transactional
    public MyEntity save(MyEntity model) {
        // more complex logic here: save if not exists
        // omitted for brevity
        var savedEntity = recipientRepository.save(entity); 
        var createdExternalEntity = restClient.createExternalEntity(
                savedEntity); // assume savedEntity has savedEntity.id set at this point

        // update field for a newly created 
        savedEntity.setExternalId(createdExternalEntity.getId());

        return savedEntity;
    }
```

Problem:
`savedEntity.setExternalId(createdExternalEntity.getId());` doesn't seem to work

And I even didn't try to mock`restClient.createExternalEntity` and throw Exception to see if transaction really rolls back

Comment: What is the exception/error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. `savedEntity` is `attached` 
Any change to its fields inside `@Transactional` method is reflected to DB.